# Mailgun and Laravel - Resulted in a 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: apache, laravel, post, http-status-code-413

I am trying to attach a 75M File to and email using laravel. I keep getting the error below. Using answers from other "duplicate" questions. I have added the `upload_max_size`, `post_max_size` and even tinkered with `LimitRequestBody`

Non of that is working, please what do I do, How can I send such a large attachment in Laravel (php)

Also I will appreciate some advice on how to deal with large files and emails.

```
{ "message": "Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.domain.com/messages.mime` resulted in a `413 Request Entity Too Large`}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api):

> Mailgun supports maximum messages size of 25MB.

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api